# Are Robin's Theorem and refined versions of it related to group theory?

Tags: gr.group-theory

I've been studying papers on Robin's Theorem, and also one from 2010 on a more refined version using the Dedekind $\Psi$-function instead of the $\sigma$- function. The interesting coincidences I have found are that, in Robin's Theorem, the last three exceptions to Robin's Inequality are also the number of Steiner systems in $M9$, $M10$, $M11$ and $M12$ Mathieu groups. $(840, 2520, 5040, 5040)$ the last one being used twice. (Also found from $\frac{7!}{3!}$,$\frac{7!}{2!}$, $\frac{7!}{1!}$, $\frac{7!}{0!}$  $7!$ also being characterized as $S7$. Also, $5040$ is the quotient of $\frac{|S12|}{|M12|}$.)

Now, the weighted intersections of Steiner systems can be found from $|M9|*\binom{6}{3}$, $|M10|*\binom{6}{2}$, $|M11|*\binom{6}{1}$, and $|M12|*\binom{6}{0}$. I've studied the landscape of all the 5040 Steiner systems in $M12$, to see if there is any relationship to Robin's Inequality and so forth.

I didn't think that much of it, but now after reading the paper on the Dedekind Psi function, and the refined version of Robin's Theorem, there is a simpler list of exceptions:

$(2,3,4,5,6,8,10,12,18,30)$. The coincidence here is that 12,18,30, once again the last three exceptions, are also the Coxeter order numbers for $E6$, $E7$, and $E8$ Exceptional Lie groups.

(Also the Dedekind $\Psi$ function also counts elements of the Projective Line $P1$ over the Lattice of $Z x Z$, and is an index of the modular group. Anyway, I know the McKay correspondence is between $E6$,$E7$ and $E8$ and a Fischer group, Baby Monster and the Monster, and not $M9$, $M10$, $M11$, and $M12$ but I found this interesting.)

The refined Robin's Inequality merely replaces the sigma function with the Dedekind $\psi$ function...and the exceptions with a shorter list $(2,3,4,5,6,8,10,12,18,30)$ instead of the list $(2,3,4,....840,2520,5040)$.

Robin's Inequality: $\sigma(n) < n * e^{\gamma} * ln(ln(n))$ for n > 5040 exceptions below 5040 being 2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10...840,2520,5040

"Refined" Robin's Inequality: $\psi(n) < n * e^{\gamma} * ln(ln(n))$ for n > 30
exceptions below 30 being 2,3,4,5,6,8,10,12,18,30 where $\psi(n)$ is the Dedekind psi function.

Comment: It should be noted that the Dedekind  Psi function for square free numbers is merely the sigma function

Comment: Please give a refrence to Robins paper. ( and somehow more self contained questions would be easier to understand)

Comment: It's only available in French and I haven't been able to obtain it however there are plenty of papers that discuss it which seem to be good enough to understand it... I'll find the best examples shortly.

Comment: The paper where he proved this is, Robin, Guy (1984), "Grandes valeurs de la fonction somme des diviseurs et hypothèse de Riemann", Journal de Mathématiques Pures et Appliquées. Neuvième Série 63 (2): 187–213, ISSN 0021-7824, MR774171